# How to test APIView in Django, Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making an API with Django + Django Rest Framework. I am trying to test the `GET` methods of a view:

View:

```
    class StuffView(APIView):
        queryset = Stuff.objects.none()

        def get(self, request, format=None):    
            data = Stuff.objects.all().order_by('-primaryKey')     
            StuffSerializer(data, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, 200)
```

In my test I create test data for the Stuff and then run this utilizing DRF's APIClient:

```
def test_stuff_view_get_all(self):
        response = self.client.get('/api/stuff/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), len(Stuff.objects.all().order_by('-primaryKey') ))
```

This works, but I am not sure length is the best way to compare these things. The other thing I would like to test is to make sure that it is properly ordered by primary key. Should I serialize the queryset and compare the dictionary to `response.data`?

Is there a best practice to doing this? Are there some things I am missing out on that I should be testing?

Comment: Comparing length is fine. For ordering I would simply take the first item from `data` and compare ids.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the response data with your posted test data, that will be a good test for checking the posted data content. You may also check the order in which the response data is received, by using index response.data[0] for first item, and [1] for second and so on.
self.assertEqual(response.data[0].get('score'), self.result.score)